# How to make Financial dimension as mandatory with red asterisk in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to make mandatory for dimension with red asterisk link for that           **In Product Information Management -> Financial Dimension ->Item Group and Warranty Vendor**

For these dimension i need red line.and In Financial Dimension(Tab Page) i need red asterisk.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do that, one option is modify `DimensionDefaultingControllerBase` class, `addEditControls` method.

Exactly in this code standard AX set a particular dimension as **mandatory**

```
    if (dimLinkMarkFieldOptionalEventArgs.parmCancel())
    {
        valueStringControl.mandatory(true); //Set as mandatory only particular dimension
    }
```

You can write some code to use only when `EcoResProductDetailsExtended` form is open (Or when you need it). In `Init` method it all begins this 3 lines

```
dimensionDefaultingController = DimensionDefaultingController::constructInTabWithValues(true, true, true, 0, this, tabFinancialDimensions, "@SYS138487");
dimensionDefaultingController.parmAttributeValueSetDataSource(inventTable_ds, fieldStr(InventTable, DefaultDimension));
dimensionDefaultingController.pageActivated();
```

Comment: But Item Group and Warranty vendor are not String control , all in Tab page what to do for this .

Comment: if you debug this code, you can see this code is used for each dimension (costCenter,  CustomerGroup, DataProcessing, etc) in this loop you can find your dimension and set mandatory with this code `valueStringControl.mandatory(true);`

Comment: Sir.. what is ValueStringControl   because i making mandatory for dimension please go to link  In Product Information Management -> Financial Dimension ->Item Group and Warranty Vendor These are dont have any string control please help me out.

Comment: Hi, yes I know, It's hard to explain, dimensions are create by `DimensionDefaultController` class, in this case, for the form `EcoResProductDetailsExtended` (your form) in `Init` method by 3 lines of code, can you see this line in my answerd. The process to create dimensions are complex, `ValueStringControl` become finally in the dimension of the form. In `DimensionDefaultingControllerBase` class, `addEditControls` method you can check mandatory this dimension but here the dimension is called `ValueStringControl`

Comment: Thank You Jonathan Bravetti.

Comment: one more doubt, How to make dimension value with red line so user can understand its a mandatory.

Comment: with this line of code `valueStringControl.mandatory(true);` make dimension value with red line.